# Liferay maven dependency could not be resolved

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am using liferay 6.2.10.4 enterprise edition with maven.while deploying it with maven clean package commad I got below error.

The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar:6.2.10.4, com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar:6.2.10.4, com.liferay.portal:util-taglib:jar:6.2.10.4, com.liferay.portal:util-java:jar:6.2.10.4: Could not find artifact com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar:6.2.10.4 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

I have used below as well.

```
repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>liferay-ce</id>
            <name>Liferay CE</name>
            <url>https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/liferay-ce</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>liferay-ce</id>
            <url>https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/liferay-ce/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: They are simply not in Central those versions [versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.liferay.portal%22%20AND%20a%3A%22portal-service%22).

Comment: So what is alternative as it clients projects.     <

Comment: Use an other version how should i know...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that versions doesn't exist in maven repository. You must put a correct version. For example, you can see util-taglib available versions [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal/util-taglib).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those dependencies to your own Maven Repository. If you don't already use a Repository Proxy: now is the time! (it really helps with lots of things). Sonatype Nexus or Artifactory are the most known ones. Both are good. Choose the one you like (but choose one).

I think [this maven plugin](https://github.com/mimacom/maven-liferay-plugin) has (or had?) a goal to upload the artifacts from the Enterprise Edition to the Repository Proxy. Otherwise you need to do that manually.

Comment: Okay Thanks I will try and Let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the packages you need with installation package that's available from liferay itself. Extensive manual on how to do this is available in [6.2 documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en) section "Installing Required Liferay Artifacts".

Management of your own repository of artifacts is described in section "Managing Maven Repositories". You'll need this repository anyway because EE artifacts are not available in public repos (license reasons).

Good news is that installation of nexus repository is quite easy and installation of EE artifacts is automated with ant :)