# The dependency could not be resolved

Tags: dependencies, asp.net-core, nuget

I am creating a basic ASP.Net Core project ([see link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html)). I already went through the SO questions ( [ASP.Net Core RC2 Project Ref The Dependency X could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017674/liferay-maven-dependency-could-not-be-resolved) and others) but couldn't find solution for my problem (probably my bad).

Issues are here:

[image]

[image]

Help appreciated !

Comment: Please check the HelpCenter to find out how to use tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. Don't force them into the title

Comment: Thanks Tseng, it helps

Comment: @Sami If you use the command line to run `dotnet restore` in the project folder, what is the output?